# Cordova iOS only app upload through transport requires WKWatchKitApp

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

we have an old cordova/phonegap app that we are trying to upload through Transporter, but suddenly we started getting the following error:

"Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key “WKApplication”, or “WKWatchKitApp” if your project has a WatchKit App Extension target, is required in “.app/.app” bundle. For details, see:"

We don't support Apple Watch and there is no target for Apple Watch, there does not seem to be anything to do with Apple Watch in our XCode project, yet we are getting the above complain. We were able to submit the app a month ago, so it worked then.

There has been no change to our provisioning profile.

There does not seem to be any update to the cordova plugins that we use. Also compared the solution to the last successful submission and there does not seem to be anything that changed in the project files since the last submission. The commits diff is only in JS front end side.

We using the following versions: XCode 15.0 Cordova: 12.0.0 cordova-ios: 6.3.0

I have no idea what to look for. Any ideas?